# How to search string references in specified location?

Tags: shell-script, grep, working-directory

I'm trying to find the occurrence of elements list(from a text file) in a directory.

Below is the `bash` code I'm using, but I'm unable to get the output of `grep` command on to console.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILENAME=$1

count=0

while read LINE

do

let count++

echo "$count $LINE"

grep -r $LINE /home/user/vaishnavi

done < $FILENAME

echo -e "\nTotal $count Lines read"
```

Output:

```
1 ASK
2 TELL
3 ORDER
4 NUMBER
5 SIZE
6 BASKET
7 FRUIT
8 VEGGIES
Total 8 Lines read
```

I'm getting only the list of elements but not their occurrences in the specified location.

Is anything wrong with my code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code should be like

If you wish output like

*Serial_Number   Name_Of_Element   Count
file name 1
file name 2*

```
#!/bin/bash
FILENAME=$1

count=0

while read LINE

do

let count++

VAL=$(grep -r $LINE /home/user/vaishnavi | awk -F ':' '{print $1}' | sort -u )
NUM=$(grep -r $LINE /home/user/vaishnavi | wc -l)

echo "$count $LINE $NUM"
echo "$VAL"

done < $FILENAME

echo -e "\nTotal $count Lines read"
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.
But the output doenot seems like the right one
Output: 0 ASK
Though ASK has its references in the given path.
And also when grep is executed seperately Im getting the right results.
Can you please check on this.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.
But the output doenot seems like the right one
Output: 0 ASK
Though ASK has its references in the given path.
And also when grep is executed seperately Im getting the right results.
Can you please check on this.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you need the list of files where the specified word has occered ?

Comment: yes you're right.

Comment: You could try this solution.

Comment: This is still not working
Output: 
0ASK
.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -xrHf elementsfile.txt /home/user/vaishnavi | sort | uniq -c
```

- x: match whole line (ASK should not match BASKET)
- r: scan your folder
- H: print the file name (file:match)
- f: read the elements to match from file

This is sorted by file, if you want to sort it by the matching element add:

```
| sort -k2 -t:
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.
But this not pinting my grep results.
It is giving the output as 
1 ASK
2 TELL
3 ORDER
4 NUMBER
5 SIZE
6 BASKET
7 FRUIT
8 VEGGIES
Total 8 Lines read

Comment: Use this pipeline without loop. I guess there are no matching files in your folder.